# SQL NOW() function not working properly

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to insert the date in a a query, using the `NOW()` statement.

However only the Y-m-d are being inserted correctly, while the hours, minutes and seconds are all appearing zeros ( 00:00:00 )

Any reason for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you check the type of the column you are inserting into? Make sure it's `datetime`, not just `date`.

Refer to the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

`SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`
or
`SELECT GETDATE()`
or
`Select {fn NOW()}`

Note the accolades in the function.

Comment: @ PahDaPhunk - According to the docs (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html), NOW() is a synonym for CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(). So I'm not sure how this would make a difference.

Comment: It all does the same thing. But I thought hey maybe he is not using the function correctly  by forgetting the accolades or something so I gave an alternative