# PHP MYSQLI prepared statement compare datetime to GetDate() err

Tags: php, datetime, mysqli, prepare, date-comparison

I open a connection to my database using php and mysqli and make a few queries using prepared statements where everything works dandy but in this query where I attempt to only select rides that are in the future I am inexplicably failing as soon as I add the comparison to GETDATE()

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');

if(!($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT r.destination, r.startDepartureTime, r.seats, r.priceperseat FROM ride r WHERE r.startZipCode = ? AND r.startDepartureTime > GETDATE()"))) echo "Prepare failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;

if(!$stmt->bind_param("i", $userZipCode)) echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($destination,$departure,$seats,$price);

while($stmt->fetch()){ 
   echo "Destination : $destination Departure Time : $departure Seats Available : $seats Price Per Seat : $price <br>";
}

$stmt->close();
```

The php error log reports that on the  prepare statement line

PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object

and that therefore on the bind_param line we get

PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

I originally was trying to use NOW() but tried all of the solutions in this thread [SQL NOW() function not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11762269/sql-now-function-not-working-properly) and have had no luck.

When I run the statement without the r.startDepartureTime > GETDATE() comparison everything works fine.

And I have ensured that the startDepartureTime column in my database is of type datetime. Here is an example entry : 2016-05-21 10:24:00 that I've made sure is indeed greater than the current time and in the same zipcode to ensure that Im not just receiving an empty set.

Comment: You get those error when the `->prepare()` fails but you dont catch the error and just continue with your code

Answer (score 0):

`GETDATE()` is not a MYSQL Function, `NOW()` should be what you need

Maybe what you mean to do is use less than rather than greater than in the query `r.startDepartureTime < NOW()`

If the prepare fails then you need to do something more positive that just report an error. So this kind of code will work better.

Also if the prepare fails, `$stmt` is set to `false` and therefore using `$stmt->errno` etc will not work, and will in fact generate even more confusing error messages. So in this case you have to use the connection `$con` to get the errors from

```
$sql = "SELECT r.destination, r.startDepartureTime, 
               r.seats, r.priceperseat 
        FROM ride r 
        WHERE r.startZipCode = ? 
          AND r.startDepartureTime < NOW()";

$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);

if($stmt === false) {
   echo "Prepare failed: {$con->errno} : {$con->error}";
   exit;
}
```

Comment: thank you that did the trick, I still want greater than and I appreciate the help with error handling